# How to take a transaction cut from every paypal transaction?

Tags: php, e-commerce, paypal, payment-gateway

I am having a technical problem. I am capable of making a paypal transaction call from my php website. It is an auction website. Sellers put their product on line for auction, and buyers bit. For each successful auction, the payment can be processed as a PayPal transaction.

But how can I take a cut (service fee, $1)? I am thinking of two API calls, but that requires the buyers to pay twice.
Is there any way to do it with PayPal or I need another transaction service, like Amazon Flexible Payment?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initiate a transaction from your account to the payee, this wouldn't require the user to commit two transactions.

I strongly recommend [Stripe.com](https://stripe.com/) whenever I get a chance too. The API is very easy. You can accept payments with Stripe, then when the transaction clears, have your server send the remainder to the Paypal account of the seller.

Comment: However, this requires double transaction of same order. Before it reaches the payee, the paypal takes cut twice.

Comment: Ebay gets around it by owning Paypal I guess. Financial transactions have two parties, you would need to commit 2 to be get part but using stripe to commit the second on the backend would hide that hassle from both seller and buyer.

Comment: Thanks. I will checkout stripe.com

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of routing a part of the payment from a user's PayPal transaction to yourself.  You might be better off selling vouchers ahead of time that user's can use for each transaction.  That way they're not forced to make two transactions at time of purchase.

Comment: One possible way. What if the service fee is percentage.

Comment: Then have them buy X number of credits and use the appropriate number to represent the percentage you want on each transaction.  However you choose to do it make it as painless as possible.